# How do circuit boards handle large-voltage motors?

Tags: microcontroller

How are industrial grade servos controlled? If I'm correct (which is highly unlikely,) the circuit board needs to supply the motor with power.  I'm pretty sure,though, that would fry everything on it if you tried to run a large current on it.

Comment: You can put power electronics on a circuit board too. You just need beefy enough transistors. Where's the problem?

Comment: You can also put the high-power components off the board, probably mounted on heatsinks, and connect them to the PC board and external connectors with suitable wires

Comment: [Heatsink mounted transistor modules with bolt-on connectors](https://5.imimg.com/data5/DR/RH/FU/SELLER-90219886/igbt-module-500x500.jpg) exist for the larger currents/voltages...

Comment: We need more specific information to elaborate on this (which motor, how much current). Maybe you can explain why you think it'd be a problem in your specific example...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "large-voltage" motor. Motors, like all electrical and electronic components have specific voltage ratings.

Comment: There’s plenty of Youtube vids where the electronics for electric vehicles are pulled down and explained. Basically, if it is significant current, it doesn’t find its way on a pcb - thick bits of copper is the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boards traces can be made quite thick, then can easy carry tens of amperes. And if this is not enough, you can always add more metal on top of this, see this question for a picture:

[Is soldering extra wires to increase current capacity on a pcb trace good design?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145140/is-soldering-extra-wires-to-increase-current-capacity-on-a-pcb-trace-good-design)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, large motors are controlled by

- PLC systems with interface devices mounted on DIN rails, or,
- high current connectors directly connected to studs connectors on a variable frequency drives, or
- heavy gauge wire connected directly to relays that are fed by mains power (relay coil is activated by much lower current)
- Or, like you suggested, multi-layer PCBs with 6 oz copper and short traces, some pretty high currents are possible.